# Conditional on the existence or the non existence

Tags: programming, linear-algebra

I have a nested serie of feasibility tests according to the code

```
ClearAll[a]
a = .5
maxfp =   Maximize[1, (a - 9)  x + 3 (a - 1) y <= 0 && 2 a x - ( a - 5) y <= 0 && 
  x + y == 1, {x, y}]
```

I would like to make a conditional treatment on the fact that  the problem is feasible or not. How could I refer to it as If[**maxfp feasible?**, my condition , else ]. The problem is that if I call maxfp[[1,1]], MA returns -1 not $-\infty$

Comment: Returns `{1, {x -> 1.28571, y -> -0.285714}}`, so there is no [[1,1]] part in 10.4 and 11.0.1. What version are you using?

Comment: Until now 10.1. It was only a feasible case. If you set a=2.5, the problem is unfeasible. This is standard in the case of some algorithm in fractional linear programming where you must iteratively test the feasibility of some programs and change the a value according to feasibility or non feasibility.

Comment: I think you can use `Head@maxfp[[1]]`, which returns `Integer` if it is feasible and `DirectedInfinity` otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that the first part of the [`Maximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html)result is an actual number only when the problem is feasible:

```
NumberQ[maxfp[[1]]]
```